# Suppose that every subsequence has itself a subsequence which converges to c Prove that the full sequence converges to

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

please check my proof

Because every subsequence converge to  c

we have

$|a_{1}-c|<\frac{\epsilon }{n}$

$|a_{2}-c|<\frac{\epsilon }{n}$

$|a_{3}-c|<\frac{\epsilon }{n}$

.

.

.

.

$|a_{n}-c|<\frac{\epsilon }{n}$

Now we must prove the full sequence converge to c by

$|a_{1}-c|+|a_{2}-c|+|a_{3}-c|..........+|a_{n}-c|<\frac{\epsilon }{n}+\frac{\epsilon }{n}+...\frac{\epsilon }{n}=\frac{n\epsilon }{n}=\epsilon $

therefore the full sequence converge to c too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is not correct,  a subsequence converges to $c$ does not means that $|a_i-c|<\epsilon/n$.

Here is an approach, suppose that the sequence does not converges to $c$, there exists a number $d>0$ such that for every integer $n>0$ there exists an integer $l_n>n$ such that such that $|a_{l_n}-c|>d$. But $(a_{l_n})$ has subsequence which converges to $c$. This means that there exists ${a_{l_{n_p}}}$ which converges to $c$, so there exists $n$ such that $n_p>N$ implies that $|{a_{l_{n_p}}}-c|<d$. Contradiction.